# Overcoming line breaks in a block of HTML text

Tags: html, regex, vba

I know that I shouldn't be using REGEX for parsing HTML, and I promise to check out the HTML agility pack, but in the meantime, could some expert tell me if there's a pattern that will match this entire block?

```
<tr bgcolor="#f4f4ff"><td align="center"><font size="2">42</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="2">35</font></td>
<td><font size="2"><a href="/movies/?id=bears.htm"><b>Bears</b></a></font></td>
<td><font size="2"><a href="/studio/chart/?view2=calendar&yr=2014&studio=buenavista.htm">BV</a></font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2"><b>$33,845</b></font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2"><font color="#ff0000">-60.1%</font></font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2">75</font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2"><font color="#ff0000">-35</font></font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2">$451</font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2">$17,492,470</font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2">-</font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="2">8</font></td>
</tr>
```

I'm using VBA, and regexoptions don't seem to be available.  I've fiddled endlessly, and "should works" like

```
<tr[.\n]+tr> 
<tr[.\s]+tr> 
<tr[.\x0C\x\0A]+tr>
```

don't.  I can match everything up to the first line break, then I hit a brick wall.  Is there any workaround if the singleline option isn't available?  Maybe using the VBA REPLACE function to change all vbcrlf instances to some other character before I try to match?  And can somebody point me to an example of how much easier this would be with the HTML agility pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you've heard the warnings against using regex to parse html?

As far as I know, VBAScript doesn't have the DOTALL mode, so to match across lines we have to make a fake DOTALL dot with something like this: `(?:.|[\r\n])` or `[\s\S]`

This regex will match your block:

```
<tr[\s\S]*?</tr>
```

But if there are nested rows, you will be sorry you used regex. :)

**Sample code**

```
Dim myRegExp, myMatches, matched_block
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "<tr[\s\S]*?</tr>"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
If myMatches.Count >= 1 Then
    matched_block = myMatches(0).Value
Else
    matched_block = ""
End If
```

Comment: Outstanding ... I thought that I'd found the answer here {link](http://aliraza.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/regular-expression-for-html-table-parsing/), but the row expression -- `<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>` -- only worked when there were no line feeds.  I had to eliminate all the line feeds to get it to work.  Yours works perfectly without this extra step.  One thing I don't understand, though -- why does it need _both "*" and "?" to work?  How do they work in tandem?  Can you translate your pattern to English?

Comment: It is not the same `?` as in `\d?` for instance. The `?` makes the `*` lazy: it only matches up to the next `</tr>`. Without it, the `*` is greedy and rolls down to the end of the string before backtracking to the last `</tr>`. Read [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)

Comment: Boy, the nuances that can make all the difference ... this explains why I was getting the whole table rather than just one row while I was experimenting.  One last question: Now that I have the <tr>'s, I need to get the info in the <td>'s.  This pattern `>[^<\f\n\r\t\v]+<` seems to do the job, but it leaves me with the nuisance of having to strip the brackets from each match.  Do you know of a better pattern that will extract JUST the data?

Comment: Comments are not a good format for this. It's hard for me to understand what you want. Please ask a new question.

Comment: OK, done.  The thread title is "Is it possible to extract ONLY the data between <td and /td>?". @user3732258

Comment: @user3732258 Thanks, that's much tidier. Replied with demo and explanation, let me know if you have questions. :)